How to add a new line in textContent in javascript
I have the following method -
    function callBack(data1, predicted_label){
        const resultParagraph = document.getElementById("resultParagraph"); 
        resultParagraph.textContent = `Sentiment: ${predicted_label}`;
        const historyList = document.getElementById("historyList");
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.textContent = `Text: ${data1} Sentiment: ${predicted_label}`;
        historyList.prepend(listItem);  
    }

I want to add a new line between Text: ${data1} and Sentiment: ${predicted_label}.
I've tried adding \n, tried adding a <br> tag but nothing seems to work.

are you sure this doesn't work? listItem.textContent = Text: ${data1}\nSentiment: ${predicted_label};

yup tried that @ChrisG

HTML rendering doesn't respect newlines - you'll need to use innerHTML instead of textContent and add a <br> tag where you want the line break

You can use CSS to style the list item to display "Text" and "Sentiment" on separate lines.
function callBack(data1, predicted_label) {
    const resultParagraph = document.getElementById("resultParagraph");
    resultParagraph.textContent = `Sentiment: ${predicted_label}`;
    const historyList = document.getElementById("historyList");
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = `Text: ${data1}\nSentiment: ${predicted_label}`;
    listItem.style.whiteSpace = "pre-line"; // style for line breaks
    historyList.prepend(listItem);
}

